# mysql case insensitive issue even with COLLATE utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, case, collation

Let us say I have a field col2 and has a value of caSEINseNSItiVe.  Running this query below does not give me col2=CD.  I tried LIKE and LIKE BINARY.

```
SELECT col1,
CASE 
  WHEN col2 = 'CASEINSENSITIVE' THEN 'CD'
  ELSE col2
END 
FROM Table COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

The table has collation setting of utf8_bin.  I cant change the settings.  I need to switch to utf8_general_ci when creating reports while keep utf8_bin as default.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the UPPER or LOWER funcions like so:

```
SELECT col1,
CASE 
  WHEN UPPER(col2) = 'CASEINSENSITIVE' THEN 'CD'
  WHEN UPPER(col2) = 'ANYUPPERTEXT' THEN 'UP'
  WHEN LOWER(col2) = 'somelowertext' THEN 'LW'
  WHEN UPPER(col2) = UPPER('anytext that will also be UPPERed') THEN '??'
  ELSE col2
END 
FROM Table
```